# Liblua5.3-lpeg.so.2: cannot open shared object file

Tags: linux, lua, apt-get, nmap

I have updated my Kali Linux 2.0 using `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`.

Since then, `nmap` have stopped working for me.

I receive the following error on command line:

```
root@kali:/usr/local/lib# nmap
nmap: error while loading shared libraries: liblua5.3-lpeg.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I already have tried to update `nmap` using `apt-get update nmap`, and also creating a symbolic link using: `ln -s liblua.so.5.3 liblua.so.5.2`. Both didn't help.

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Try apt-get install -f

Comment: Have tried, didn't help..

Comment: maybe remove nmap and install again

Answer (score 1):

You have a library version dependency problem. Nmap needs the `lpeg` library for Lua 5.3, which is not available. The `lpeg-lua` package provides `lua5.3-lpeg` on Kali Linux, so it probably has to be updated as well. The version I see as current is 0.12.2-1.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install or update `lua-lpeg` package. So run command

`sudo apt install lua-lpeg`

If you are, don't use sudo. This will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I had a similar problem with neovim, I just installed the lua-lpeg version it required with `sudo dnf install lua5.1-lpeg` and it worked just fine.

Answer (score -2):

Have been able to fix the issue using:

```
ln -s liblua5.2-lpeg.so.2.0.0 liblua5.3-lpeg.so.2
```

Comment: This is mixing up library versions, and likely to cause problems down the line.